# How to model "stage" with both Int and Timespan - custom enum?

Tags: c#

I have a class named "Creature" which is in one of several stages.  There are only seven stages, but each stage has a different timespan that will be used throughout the application.  I'd like to do something like the following:

```
enum Stage
    {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five
    };
```

But then also somehow attach a Timespan to each of those, so that

```
Stage.One.Time
```

returns something like "one hour".  How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, enums in C# are pretty limited. You have a couple of options though:

- Create extension methods which can add whatever logic you want. You could then write:

  ```
  Stage.One.ToTimeSpan()
  ```

  (where `ToTimeSpan` is the extension method, which would probably either use a `Dictionary<Stage, TimeSpan>` or a switch statement)
- Write a "smart" enum which is actually just a type with a limited set of values:

  ```
  public sealed class Stage
  {
      public static readonly Stage One = new Stage(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
      public static readonly Stage Two = new Stage(TimeSpan.FromHours(5));
      // ...

      private readonly TimeSpan time;
      public TimeSpan Time { get { return time; } }

      private Stage(TimeSpan time)
      {
          this.time = time;
      }
  }
  ```

  The disadvantage of this is that you now can't switch on stages :(

Comment: @Mark: Yes, that's possible - but it ends up being kinda messy.